# Как сделать Плавный скролл колёсиком?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Как сделать Плавный скролл колёсиком ?

Какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3

```
body {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
```

https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-behavior

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$(document).bind( 'mousewheel', function (e) { 
var nt = $(document.body).scrollTop()-(e.deltaY*e.deltaFactor*100); 
e.preventDefault(); 
e.stopPropagation(); 
$(document.body).stop().animate( { 
     scrollTop : nt 
 } , 500 , 'easeInOutCubic' );  
} )
```

C длиной скрола (100), скоростью (500) и эфектом (easeInOutCubic) нужно поиграться

[Источник](https://toster.ru/q/90865)